# Simulate LAG with GROUP BY in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, mysql-5.6

How do I simulate LAG function from MySQL 8.0 in MySQL 5.6 where I get the previous info with same ItemID. I've created this illustration to simulate the table and the output of the query I need. The gray data is the original table and the orange is the data from the previous row with same ItemID and the closest previous date.

[image]

I've tried joining the table with it self on A.ItemID = B.ItemID AND B.Date < A.Date. I've also tried group by ItemID and tried getting the max date below the current date.

I've tried this aswell.

```
SET @lag = -1;
SELECT *, @lag PreviousInfo, @lag:=Info CurrentInfo FROM Table1
```

However this always just returns the info from the previous row and is not grouped by the ItemID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two correlated subqueries:

```
select
    t.*,
    (
        select date 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.itemid = t.itemid and t1.date < t.date
        order by t.date desc
        limit 1
    ) previous_date,
    (
        select info 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.itemid = t.itemid and t1.date < t.date
        order by t.date desc
        limit 1
    ) previous_info
from mytable t
```

However this does not scale well when you need to recover more columns from the previous record. In that case, we can self-join with a `not exists` condition to filter on the previous record:

```
select
    t.*,
    tlag.date previous_date,
    tlag.info previous_info
from mytable t
left join mytable tlag
    on  tlag.itemid = t.itemid
    and tlag.date   < t.date
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where t1.itemid = t.itemid and t1.date < t.date and t1.date > tlag.date
    )
```

For performance of both queries, consider the following an index on `(item_id, date)`. You might want to add `info` to the index, like: `(item_id, date, info)`, especially with the first query, so both subqueries are *covered* by the index.

Comment: I've managed to achieve the desired effect using two variables PreviousItemID and PreviousInfo and then I can SELECT IF(PreviousItemID = ItemID, PreviousInfo , -1) PreviousInfo, PreviousInfo:=Info CurrentInfo, PreviousItemID :=ItemID CurrentItemID ORDER BY ItemID ASC, Date ASC. Do you know the performance difference using the 2 variables compared to your join and sub query solution?

Comment: @TobiasKnudsen: yes it is (sometimes) possible to emulate window functions with user variables. I am not a big fan of these solutions, that I find harder to read and write, hence I offered the above solutions. You might want to assess the performance of each solution against your real dataset (I would be interested to know, too). I added an index suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Alright, I found a flaw in my solution and I've just tried implementing your solution. So far it's working perfectly. I have a database with about 23.000.000 rows and with the sub query and join I'm able to retrieve the data in about 1 sec. I'm considering just adding the column previous_info or maybe just previous ID to the table structure. That might speed up the join alot. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way on a large data set is probably to use variables, but you have to do so carefully:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (case when (@i <> itemid)
             then (case when (@prevd := date) = null  -- never happens
                        else null
                   end)                 
             when (@stash := @prevd) = null  -- never happens
             then null
             when (@prevd := date) = null    -- never happens
             then null
             else @x
        end) as prev_d                       
FROM (SELECT t1.*
      FROM Table1 t1
      ORDER BY itemid, date
     ) t1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @i := -1, @prevd := null) params;
```

The use of variables is very tricky because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluations of expressions in the `SELECT`.  So, this uses a `CASE` express to ensure the correct order of evaluation.

You may not need the subquery in MySQL 5.6 -- an `ORDER BY` in the outer query may handle variables (at some point around 5.6/5.7 this stopped working).